# How to use dependency injection to inject IO.gets input in Elixir?

Tags: dependency-injection, elixir

Suppose I have a function that validates user's input and then output something:

```
def set_name(user_input) do

  case !InputValidators.empty_input?(user_input) do
      true -> user_input
      false ->
        display_error(error)
        set_name(user_input)
  end
end
```

I want to be able to use IO to capture user input but I don't want to call IO.gets inside the function. I read about using dependency inject but I'm not sure how I'll go about using it in situation like this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a [behaviour](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Module.html#module-behaviour) in the first place.

```rb
defmodule Input do
  @doc "Defines a user input method"
  @callback get_user_input() :: binary()
end
```

Now you are to implement this behaviour for different methods (`IO.gets` only for now):

```rb
defmodule IOInput do
  @behaviour Input

  @impl true
  def get_user_input(), do: IO.gets
end
```

And, finally, use it:

```rb
def set_name(user_input, input_source \\ IOInput) do
  case !InputValidators.empty_input?(user_input) do
    true -> user_input
    false ->
      display_error(error)
      set_name(input_source.get_user_input()) # HERE
  end
end
```

`input_source` here is a *dependency*, passing an implementation is an *injection*.